# Compile-time recursion in variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

my goal is to make a class containing a tuple consisting of classes all of which have a method void update() which allows all the contained update() methods to be called in a row with minimal overhead. Here is my code:

```c
template< typename... Tel >
class ExecSet
{
private:
  std::tuple<Tel...> m_data;

   //Compile-time Recursive
   template<int _iter, typename _Head, typename... _Tail>
   inline void _update()
   {
     std::get<_iter>(m_data).update();
     _update< _iter + 1, _Tail... >();
   }

   //Base case
   template<int _iter>
   inline void _update()
   {
     //Do nothing here
   }

public:
   inline void update()
   {
     _update<0, Tel...>();
   }
};

class Foo
{
//..
inline void update()
  {
    std::cout << "An update of Foo " << m_i << "\n";
  }

  private:
  int m_i;
};

class Bar
{
//..
inline void update()
  {
    std::cout << "An update of Bar " << m_i << "\n";
  }

  private:
  int m_i;
};
```

The code compiles and a test executes as expected. My question is, can I be 100% sure that ExecSet::update() will be completely inlined along with every recursed call made inside? I would imagine it should because this is all determined at compile time. And under -O3 everything should be inlined too right?

Comment: Why don't you just check it yourself?!

Comment: With the -Winline option it doesn't issue any warnings, but its known that that warning might not be issued despite a function not getting inlined. The asm appears to inline it (though I'm not 100% confident about this), but since I plan to use this sort of template often I don't want to check the asm every time. I'm hoping to get some insight as to whether or not something like this is sure to get inlined in general

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. C++ standard does not guarantee function to be inlined even if you add `inline` specifier.

Comment: Yes I know it's not guaranteed, my question is can I expect it to be inlined in this kind of situation

Comment: not that different compiler supply a way to force inlining. Gcc has "always_inline", Visual C++ has __forceinline and other compiler probably have other keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the compiler to emit symbolic assembly instead of machine code and check for yourself. That said, having done just that on multiple occasions myself, I'm sure no serious compiler would leave such a mundane opportunity to inline unused. The things modern compilers do, they are pure *magic*.